# The 'any()' or 'all()' function in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to check two conditions? For example,

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])    
if any(a != 0 and a!=1)==True:
    do something
```

EDIT: Answer provided. No need for any more input. Cheers

Comment: You're misusing `any()`, I guess. From the docs:  _Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False._

Comment: Wouldn't it be `any(a != 0) or any(a != 1)` since these are `numpy` arrays?

Comment: Also, why is this being so violently downvoted?

Comment: The question is completely different from the title.

Comment: @SethMMorton, no idea. Let's upvote?

Comment: @ForceBru Well, I don't upvote just to reverse a downvote.  I'm not sure this question is worth upvotes, but I also don't think it is worth downvotes either.

Comment: @SethMMorton Probably cause the OP has put in very little effort to make himself clear.

Comment: You need to pass an generator or iterable.

Comment: @SethMMorton: there is too little context here to make much sense of the question. There is also the nagging suspicion the OP really wanted to use [`numpy.any()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html), but hasn't made that clear. There is no expected output, no explanation of what problem they are solving, no apparent effort to research how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a generator object or iterable containing Booleans. The generator expression below contains only true and false, depending if the item is a number other than one and zero.

```
if any(i != 0 and i != 1 for i in a):
    print "I'll do something here"
```

Problem is, you were trying to test if the **array** was not equal to zero and one, thus passing a single Boolean rather than an iterable or generator. You want to test the individual values not the array itself.

Comment: But the OP is probably confusing the built-in with the [`numpy` version](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html).

Comment: Thanks, this works as required. Thank you also for being polite and succinct in your answer. It is much appreciated when people aren't rude when answering a question. Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome, just be sure to mark my solution as answer with the check mark to the side.

Answer (score 0):

`Numpy` is an overkill and `any()` is useless. Use `Set` instead

```
if set(arr) - set([1,2]):
    do something
```

Comment: What if they are using `numpy` for other reasons?

Comment: @SethMMorton: OP needs to elaborate. As the problem lies, the answer is sufficient. So instead of just stating the solution I made it clear that Numpy is an overkill for the stated problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to perform some action for all elements of `a` that are not (e.g.) 0 or 1, you could filter the array first:

```
for element in filter(lambda x: x != 0 and x != 1, array):
    #dosomething with element
```

Or, for a more readable version if you're not used to anonymous functions:

```
def func(a):
    return a != 0 and a != 1

for element in filter(func, array):
    #dosomething with element
```

Comment: Any is just being used correctly. I don't see any need for filter, just fix the any argument as I have done in my answer.

Comment: Never used any() before, guess that's the reason I approached it differently. The any() solution is quite nice.